# Odoo - Multiple Conditions with OR in attrs

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, attrs.xml

I am trying to create multiple condition in attrs to make a field invisible based on selection of another field

```
<field name="pickup_date" string="Pick up Datetime" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('metal_movement_type','!=','AC'),('metal_movement_type','!=','IPPU')]}"/>
```

What i want to do i want to make this field invisible in all case other then user select `AC OR IPPU` in `metal_movement_type` selection field. I think i wrote this correct but its not working.

Comment: your answer is correct, please check if  'AC; and 'IPPO' are  the correct key of selection field. (ex:field.selection([('key','value1').....],string='')),check if in your condition you are given the key not the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "in" or "not in" operator for multiple values, for attrs you can write as following :

```
"attrs"="{'invisible':[('field','not in',(values))]}"
```

You should try this :

```
<field name="pickup_date" string="Pick up Datetime" attrs="{'invisible':[('metal_movement_type','not in',('AC','IPPU'))]}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

### try it

```
<field name="pickup_date" string="Pick up Datetime" attrs="{'invisible':[('metal_movement_type','not in',['AC','IPPU'])]}"/>
```